# Create REST service in an existing MVC app to be consumed by Xamarin app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have an existing MCV mobile site, and I am creating a mobile app using Xamarin.  I would like to use the same services contained in my MVC app to support the Xamarin app.  I have tried creating a REST service in my MVC app to be consumed by the Xamerin app a number of ways, but have found issues with each.

My first attempt was to create an Action that returned a JsonResult and to call that from the Xamarin app.  That worked, except the response that was returned is a JsonResult, not just JsonData, and when I attempted to parse it into a generic object I get an error.

Example of the JsonResult:
{{"ContentEncoding": null, "ContentType": null, "Data": "[{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"Calendar\",\"Category\":null,\"Price\":0},{\"Id\":2,\"Name\":\"Center\",\"Category\":null,\"Price\":0},{\"Id\":3,\"Name\":\"Maps\",\"Category\":null,\"Price\":0}]", "JsonRequestBehavior": 0, "MaxJsonLength": null, "RecursionLimit": null}}

Error:
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
  at System.Json.JsonValue.op_Implicit (System.Json.JsonValue value) [0x00000] in :0

My next attempt was to create a new controller inherited from ApiController with a simple Get().  When I attempt to call this I get the error:
The IControllerFactory 'mobile.Infrastructure.DependencyInjection.StructureMapControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'appmenu'.

although the routing information in the RequestContext object is correct, so the routing is being parsed properly, and the controller name *is* AppMenuController.

At this point I'm not sure if I'm on the right path or not.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post code of the class the you are trying to parse to?

Comment: I wasn't trying to parse into a defined class, I wanted to create a generic class thd then just pull the Data attribute off.

Answer (score 0):

I choose a different path.  Rather than tie my MVC site and WCF service into the same project; I deliberately kept them separate.  Mostly due to scaling concerns.  It is a lot easier for me to ramp up instances behind my load balancer depending on which project gets the most usage.  I can pretty much assure myself, that mobile usage will quite probably be quite higher than web, in my use cases currently.  Plus, I had to have a security implementation for mobile.

I advocate considering your security implementation on your Mobile Service, prior to building it.  Making security last, can get you in a pickle, unless you are building an enterprise internal app, and your devices are used within your local network / or over VPN.

If you are building something for education, there is a standard much like HIPAA in the medical industry, that requires your data be handled in particular ways.

Also, rather than use System.Json, I'd use the JSON.net component on the store.  It makes things a bit cleaner, and you'll find yourself having to do very strange things in System.JSON.  The code just isn't as intuitive as JSON.net, or I assume ServiceStack.

Comment: Thanks. Those are valid points, they don't help with this particular issue since I already have the MVC app written and just need to get one set of Json data from it.  I am using JSON.Net in Xamarin, which is why I was surprised it couldn't parse the JsonResult into an object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what changed, but now the same code appears to be returning a Json string , not a JsonResult.  When I put the url for the htt request in a browser I get the Json, not the JsonResult as before, so something must have changed in my MVC code.